# change activeX checkbox caption on cell value excel

Tags: checkbox, excel-2010, caption, activexobject

I have two activeX checkboxes (checkbox7 and checkbox10) and I would like the caption that is shown next to the tickbox to change with the value of Sheet1 cell J13. 
J13 can change value by an IF statement

I've tried a couple of things. Tried using a code I found online but it was to create multiple checkboxes from scratch and then change the caption. I was trying to isolate the part where they change the caption and duplicating it, but that didn't do anything for me.

This is what I have now:

```
>     Sheets("Customer View").OLEObjects("CheckBox7").Object.Caption = Sheets("Customer View").Range("J13").Value
    Sheets("Customer View").OLEObjects("CheckBox10").Object.Caption = Sheets("Customer View").Range("J13").Value
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? and share more details please.

Comment: Have you tried the answer provided?

Comment: I haven't tried the provided answer. I had temporarily fixed the problem by removing the caption and simply linking the underlying cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually just went with the most simple solution: Leave the caption of the checkbox empty, and position the checkbox so that it lines up with an empty cell. Then I just use that cell to show the text I want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code resides in the workbook containing sheet `Customer View` insert this code in your procedure.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Customer View")
    .CheckBox7.Caption = .Range("J13").Value2
    .CheckBox10.Caption = .Range("J13").Value2
End With
```